# Duvida em desenvolvimento de webservice para APP(android) e WEB(php)

Tags: php, java, node.js, app, apk

Olá, estamos desenvolvendo uma APP para android e essa vai fazer uma consulta em um webservice(que ainda não esta feito) para validar dados solicitados pela APP. 
O mesmo projeto roda na web e esta desenvolvido em php, jquery etc.

Então tenho 2 aplicações uma para WEB(php) acessada por PC,Tablet, Celular e outra  somente para Android (.apk), as duas versões fazem a mesma coisa basicamente que é consultar dados em um webservice, este irá retornar dados para as aplicações com informações da consulta solicitada.

Pergunta: Como as duas aplicações (web e apk) irão fazer consultas nesse webservice que vamos desenvolver, qual a melhor opção para desenvolver este webservice de maneira que o mesmo seja rápido e atenda as duas aplicações?  Desenvolver em PHP, JAVA, NODEJS? Qual diferença entre cada webservice, alguma vantagem que algum tem sobre o outro? Se precisar de mais informações favor comentar.

Já tenho algumas dicas que andei pesquisando, quero uma ajuda e um parecer de alguem que já tenha feito algo parecido.

Espero ter deixado claro a pergunta e explicação. Desde já Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que o melhor para ajudar é desde já definir que tipos de webservices pode encontrar aos dias de hoje "os mais comuns".

Defino duas situações embora um seja na realidade um protocolo:

1. Webservice SOAP - Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) um padrão que utiliza o XML como base da sua arquitectura. Pode ser utilizado em SMTP, HTTP, FTP etc. Exige suporte de "middleware", mecanismo bem definido para definir serviços como WSDL + XSD, WS-Policy retornará dados estruturados em XML
2. Webservice RESTFul - Representational State Transfer (REST) de serviços web. São serviços da Web de segunda geração. Serviços Web RESTful, comunicacam via HTTP e ao contrário de um serviço baseado em SOAP não necessita da estrutura XML ou das definições de serviço WSDL-API. HTTP simples não sendo necessário nenhum "middleware". Padrão, REST pode retornar XML, texto simples, JSON, HTML etc

Já utilizei os dois e ainda utilizo mas tenho ao longo do tempo abandonado o SOAP e substituído por serviços REST equivalentes. E porquê?

Como profissional sigo o mercado e a tendência é claramente o REST certamente vê muita referência ao REST API. Pessoalmente entendo que o REST é definitivamente o caminho actual para criar um serviço Web.

O seu API será mais limpo e mais fácil de entender/descobrir. Ao sincronizar dados com um site e ou aplicativo, é provavelmente mais fácil para descansar o utilizador porque você pode simplesmente dizer sincronização ("/artigos/1/") ou qualquer outra coisa. Mapear operações é fácil... operações CRUD, etc.

Dito isto resta a resposta directa à sua pergunta:

> Desenvolver em PHP, JAVA, NODEJS?

Da minha experiência iria pelo PHP. É uma linguagem "script" de servidor, suporta muito bem o protocolo HTTP, a comunidade é extensa e cheia de exemplos mas como razão principal olho para a sua experiência.

Tendo dito na pergunta que já tem um projecto WEB feito em PHP e JQUERY é indicador que já detêm conhecimento nesta linguagem pelo que a sua curva de aprendizagem será certamente inferior às outras e este sinceramente é no meu entender o motivo principal.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que precisava ouvir.